# Github Desktop - New Account

Tags: github, github-desktop

I'm having problems with Github Desktop...

I had an account, while studying at Uni, and used Github Desktop the last few months there (instead of command prompts).

Now, I have created a new account on Github and would like to keep using Github Desktop to create new repositories and newly made code snippets.

However.... Even if I sign out from Github Desktop (my Uni account) and log in with my new account credentials for Github, and then push my new repos there, it still goes to my previous (old) account?

What am I missing?
What should I do?